# What's the difference between "env" and "set" (on Mac OS X or Linux)?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, environment-variables

I get similar results running "env" and "set". Set gives more results - is it a superset of env?

The man page for set doesn't give any information. How do these commands work and what's the difference?

Comment: Will probably get better answers for this sort of thing in http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: It is a perfectly fine question for StackOverflow; it is about shell programming (and notice that 'programming' appears in the subject).

Comment: Since `set` is a shell builtin, we need `help set` to view the manual.  `env` is not a shell builtin and `man env` would show the manual.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Long story short: `set` can see shell-local variables, `env` cannot.

Shells can have variables of 2 types: locals, which are only accessible from the current shell, and (exported) environment variables, which are passed on to every executed program.

Since `set` is a *built-in* shell command, it also sees shell-local variables (including shell functions). `env` on the other hand is an independent executable; it only sees the variables that the shell passes to it, or environment variables.

When you type a line like `a=1` then a local variable is created (unless it already existed in the environment). Environment variables are created with `export a=1`

Comment: `set` can also report shell options (with the `-o` switch) which `env` doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to limit the output of the `set` command to variables only, you may run it in POSIX mode:

```
type -a env set
help set
(set -o posix; set) | nl
```

If you need finer control over listing specific variables, you may use Bash builtins such as `declare` or `compgen`, or some other Bash tricks.

```
man bash | less -p '-A action$'  # info on complete & compgen

# listing names of variables
compgen -A variable | nl       # list names of all shell variables
echo ${!P*}                    # list names of all variables beginning with P

compgen -A export | nl         # list names of exported shell variables
export | nl                    # same, plus always OLDPWD
declare -px | nl               # same

declare -pr                    # list readonly variables

# listing names of functions           
compgen -A function | nl
declare -F | nl
declare -Fx | nl

# show code of specified function
myfunc() { echo 'Hello, world!'; return 0; }
declare -f myfunc
```

Comment: Goddamnit! How in the world this answer doesn't have many more upvotes? Thanks a lot my dude for posting this, traditional shells (!{fish,nu}) can be quite cryptic at times.

Answer (score 4):

`set` is a shell builtin, while `env` is a program (/usr/bin/env)

`set` does several things, but by itself it lists the shell variables. It can also set/toggle switches, such as `set +x` or `set -v` etc.

`env` by itself lists the exported environment variables, which are available to sub-processes. It can set (and export) a/some environment variables `env foo=bar this=that` and unset them `env -u foo`, and can run a program in a modified environment `env EDITOR=atom git commit`

See `man 1 env` for more information.

Comment: No - `set` lists local variables (non-environment variables) as well as environment variables.

Comment: @Jonathan - I think this is really a change in terminology from when I started, and some differences between csh and sh/ksh - and bash draws from both shell families. "Back in my day" ... the distinction made was always whether or not the variable was exported, but both were referred to as "environment" variables. Calling them "local" vs. "environment" variables came later. (Of course, I originally learned in a BSD csh setting, and that could be the difference in thinking & talking about it)

Comment: Well, when I was learning, environment variables were those that were exported (or, in the C shell world, setenv'd); the others were not in the environment of any process except the shell itself, and were emphatically not relayed to child processes, so they weren't in 'the environment' in any meaningful way - they were local to the shell and not environment variables.  However, it is possible that you learned a different vocabulary for the same phenomena - but I think the vocabulary you learned (described above) deviated from the norms of the Unix community at large.

Comment: @StephenP: The `csh` command `setenv` gives a clue as to the intended terminology: "set *env*ironment variable".  I think maybe the people you learned from were using the wrong terminology.  It's also possible that there was a shift (these things happen) but the `setenv` command makes me guess otherwise.  I was using `csh` back in '92 or '93, but I don't recall the terminology clearly... and perhaps you're referring to a much earlier time...