# Accessing environment vars from Ruby using a .env (dotenv) file in zsh

Tags: ruby, environment-variables, zsh

I'm using the oh-my-zsh [dotenv plugin](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/dotenv), which loads `.env` file, if it exists, whenever I `cd` into a project directory.

I know it works because I can see my custom environment vars set when I run the `set` cmd.

I can can also echo my custom environment variable from command line:

```
$ echo $FOO
'foo'
```

However, I *cannot* access this environment variable via the `env` command or Ruby:

```
$ irb
2.4.1 :001 > ENV['FOO']
nil
```

How can I  make sure environment variables loaded from my `.env` are accessible from Ruby?

Comment: does it work if you `require 'dotenv/load'` ?

Comment: I'm not using the `dotenv` gem (just the oh-my-zsh plugin) as I was under the impression that the shell plugin would export the vars automatically.

Comment: It should. Have you tried running `export FOO=test` and then irb: `ENV['FOO']` ? That works here in iTerm2 on Mac OS.

Comment: If I manually export, then yea, that works. I was looking at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657060/whats-the-difference-between-env-and-set-on-mac-os-x-or-linux#5657113) and I think the issue is that the vars are only shell-local, which `env` cannot see. But I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to use the gem? If the `.env` is in the working directory, it will work. Seems strange to rely on zsh functionality within your ruby program. You can easily exclude your `.env` file from a repo

Comment: Already have a .env in our repo (w/o values of course). Not averse to adding the gem, just wanted to rule out needing a new dep simply because I didn't understand how the export actually works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to what is stated in the [documentation of `dotenv`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/dotenv), you actually need to use the `export` keyword within the `.env` file in order to make the parameters available to the environment, e.g.

```
export FOO=foo
```

The only exception would be, if the parameter was already an environment variable. For example if it had been exported in `~/.zshrc` or if it was already part of the environment `zsh` got when it started (e.g. `PATH` or `HOME`).

---

All `dotenv` does is automatically sourcing any `.env` file when changing into a directory. There is no additional "magic". That means `.env` needs to be a valid `zsh` script and its content is run in the context of the current shell session (essentially as if you typed it manually).

It also means that the usual rules apply. That is, just settings parameters makes them available to the current shell context only. In order to make them available as environment variables they need to be exported (either before, during or after being set). So unless a parameter has already been exported before, `export` is not really "optional" in `.env`.

Comment: Yup. Adding `export` to my `.env` file resolved the issue.