# Unexpected entry at end of bash environment variable list

Tags: bash, environment-variables

When I open a terminal under Ubuntu 18.04.4. and I enter "set" with no arguments, the end of the environment variable list looks like this:

```
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
XDG_VTNR=1
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
_=macOrg
command_not_found_handle () 
{ 
    if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
        /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1";
        return $?;
    else
        if [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
            /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1";
            return $?;
        else
            printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" 1>&2;
            return 127;
        fi;
    fi
}
```

Bash version is 4.4.20(1). Can anyone explain why the *command_not_found_handle ()*  function body is appearing here?
Thanks

Comment: What does `man bash` say about the keyword `command_not_found_handle`?

Comment: Because your OS included in shell initialization by default

Comment: In ubuntu-16, I found it in `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I'm seeing it now. I didn't realize that there is a difference between set and env as described here [set vs env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657060/whats-the-difference-between-env-and-set-on-mac-os-x-or-linux#:%7E:text=Long%20story%20short%3A%20set%20can,%2Dlocal%20variables%2C%20env%20cannot.&text=Since%20set%20is%20a%20built,to%20it%2C%20or%20environment%20variables.)

To quote:

> Long story short: set can see shell-local variables, env cannot. ...
> Since set is a built-in shell command, it also sees sees shell-local
> variables (including shell functions). env on the other hand is an
> independent executable; it only sees the variables that the shell
> passes to it, or environment variables.Apr 14, 2011

Thanks to those who responded.